# ¿Por qué no estoy pudiendo leer datos recibidos a través de un Socket en un Text Box?

Tags: c#, .net, socket

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de Windows Form en C#, en la cual tengo que leer datos (mensajes) enviados desde un controlador de compresor de aire a través de Ethernet por TCP/IP. El problema que estoy teniendo, es que recibo esos datos, pero no se están visualizando en el Text Box que estoy designando para eso.
Puedo afirmar que la información está llegando bien, ya que desarrollé el mismo programa pero adaptado a una aplicación de Consola, y los datos sí aparecen en la Consola. ¿Por qué podrá ser que no se visualizan en el Text Box? No pude encontrar nada en Internet.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace Sullair
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private TcpClient client;
    public StreamReader STR;
    public string receive;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        IPAddress[] localIP = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) //Recepción contínua de mensajes en el background
    {
        while (client.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                receive = STR.ReadLine();
                this.textBox2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { textBox2.AppendText("Exemys : " + receive + "\r\n"); }));
                receive = "";
            }
            catch(Exception x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //conecta al servidor
    {
        client = new TcpClient();
        IPEndPoint IP_End = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox5.Text), int.Parse(textBox6.Text));

        try
        {
            client.Connect(IP_End);
            if(client.Connected)
            {
                textBox2.AppendText("Connected to Exemys!" + "\r\n");
                STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());

                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); //empieza a recibir informacion
            }
        }
        catch(Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: este mensaje aparece? textBox2.AppendText("Connected to Exemys!" + "\r\n");

Comment: y como nota, usa Enviroment.newline en lugar de "\r\n"

Comment: @LuisFernando en un textbox dentro del único formulario que tiene el programa

Comment: @gbianchi ésto es lo que aparece en el textbox: "Exemys :". Eso simplemente, y se repite ya que los datos van llegando pero no aparecen.

Comment: saca esta linea, y dime que pasa receive = "";

Comment: @gbianchi sucede lo mismo, no cambia en nada. Pareciera como si fuese un problema de formato, pero me parece raro ya que estoy recibiendo mensajes así: "02N0,0,2,E,C86", los cuales pueden ser leídos por un textbox.

Comment: descartemos problemas.. podrias armar el string que le pasas al textbox antes, mostrarlo por consola y despues pasarselo al textbox?

Comment: @gbianchi ya lo hice, en la consola sí aparece la información, pero en el text box no

Comment: y si le pasas ese string construido nuevo al textbox tampoco? tendra algun caracter raro que no estas viendo?

Comment: @gbianchi lo que acabo de hacer es definir un string asignandole el mensaje que recibo desde el controlador (copiado desde Hyperterminal que me deja ver los mensajes recibidos), y lo asigno al textbox y sí aparece. Pero cuando inicio el ciclo automático de lectura desde el socket, sigue pasando lo mismo. Es muy raro

Comment: debe venir basura en el string, que hyper te borra, y que el textbox no entiende y por eso no te lo imprime.. deberias mandar eso a un archivo y verlo en binario a ver que tiene...

Comment: @gbianchi podría ser, lo que me parece raro es que hoy con este mismo código hice debug del programa, y en la primer línea me mostró el texto, y luego volvió a mostrar mensajes en blanco. Luego nunca más

Comment: @gbianchi te quería decir que tu comentario me ayudó mucho! Hoy me acordé de que pusiste "debe venir basura en el string (...) por eso no te lo imprime" entonces lo que hice fue tomar una parte del mensaje recibido haciendo `variable.Substring` y funciono! omití el primer carácter que se ve que era el conflictivo y ahora si me está imprimiendo los valores en el textbox. Gracias!!

Comment: genial.. por favor construye una respuesta con eso.. asi la pregunta no queda huerfana. saludos!